# Stack in spting-boot

Tags: spring-boot, stack

i am working on a paint project using spring boot for the back end. i used the stack for undo/redo any move i was saving the current shapes that are painted in the stack, but whenever i am pushing new shapes like {circle, rectangle, line} all the stack elements are updated to be the last pushed shapes so all the elements in the stack will be like this [{circle, rectangle, line},{circle, rectangle, line}, ... ].

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTGZW.png)
[code run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFGma.png)
for example in this code i was expecting that the stack will be containing [{circle}, {circle, line}], but the output was [{circle, line}, {circle, line}]

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new object after adding it to the stack as its map so it will update the existing map not create a new map. Add the following after `test.push(shapes)`

```
shapes = new HashMap<>(shapes);
```